# com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 403: Forbidden while accessing office 365 sharepoint

Tags: java, sharepoint

I am getting following error while using the SharePoint web service:

com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server
sent HTTP status code 403

I am trying to access office365 sharepoint using the following code:

```
public void querySharePointFolder(ListsSoap ls) throws Exception {  
    try
    {
                GetListItems.ViewFields viewFields = null;
    GetListItems.QueryOptions msQueryOptions = new GetListItems.QueryOptions();
    GetListItems.Query msQuery = new GetListItems.Query();
    msQuery.getContent().add(createSharePointCAMLNode(query));
    msQueryOptions.getContent().add(createSharePointCAMLNode(this.queryOptions));
    GetListItemsResponse.GetListItemsResult result = ls.getListItems(
            properties.getProperty("folder"), "", msQuery, viewFields, "",
            msQueryOptions, "");
    writeResult(result.getContent().get(0), System.out);

    Element element = (Element)result.getContent().get(0);
    NodeList nl = element.getElementsByTagName("z:row");
    for(int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++){
        Node node = nl.item(i);
        logger.debug("ID: " + node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("ows_ID").getNodeValue());
        logger.debug("FileRef: " + node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("ows_FileRef").getNodeValue());
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But its showing the error at following line:

GetListItemsResponse.GetListItemsResult result =ls.getListItems(properties.getProperty("folder"), "", msQuery, viewFields, "",msQueryOptions, "");
Can you please help me out over this as after using different different approaches i am still getting the same issue 403: Forbidden.

I am using the same credential here through which i had created the folder over SharePoint. Do I need any other privileges for that credential to get the access.